# PHP статистика просмотров

Tags: php, mysql

Решил поставить на сайт счетчик просмотров конкретной страницы, 
то есть открыл человек статью и видит сколько человек смотрели данную статью,
что читать? где смотреть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот описание для начинающих:
[php+mysql](http://wm-help.net/my-articles/article/counter-views-on-all-site.php-mysql.htm) либо пишем просто в файл [php+write_to_file](http://omsk777.ru/counter.html) как удобнее. а вообще учителсь пользоваться гуглом....

Comment: имелось ввиду можете ли дать направление на надежные источники

Comment: надежные источники в плане чего? это примеры как это можно реализовать. счетчиков по сети много.

Answer (score 3):

Сохраняешь в базе количество просмотров для этой страницы. При новом просмотре делаешь +

Comment: Всё так, но дополнил бы еще проверкой по ip или сессии, для более-менее точного количества и дабы избежать нереальных размеров счётчика из-за чьего-либо флуда.

Answer (score 2):

Поставить счётчик типа Яндекс.Метрики только на искомую страницу? =)

Comment: зачем только на искомую, можно на весь сайт поставить, а дальше  установить нужные "цели"...